# Problem creating image of repeating gratings over time

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying to create an image with `plt.imshow` that will contain several gratings (blocks of black and white stripes) separated in time. In between I want to have gray blocks. This corresponds to the times I presented a grating stimulus in my experiment and the times were nothing was shown (inter stimulus periods - gray blocks).

I already have my time array and I have already extracted the start and end indices in this array where the stimuli start and end. I just want to create the image now.

I have around 40 presentations of the same stimulus over my time period, so I need for example 40 grating blocks separated by gray regions.

I first started by trying to create just white boxes within the time periods I know the stimulus was presented and black boxes in the inter stimulus periods, but not even this seems to work. Here is my code:

```
index_pairs = [list(pair) for pair in zip(starts_of_gratings_clean, ends_of_gratings_clean)] 

# Parameters
image_height = 50 

# Initialize the final image
total_time = grating_time.to_numpy()[-1]
total_width = len(grating_time)
image = np.zeros((image_height, total_width), dtype=np.uint8)

# Iterate over the index pairs and set white regions
for start_idx, end_idx in index_pairs:
    image[:, start_idx:end_idx] = 255

# Plot the image
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray', aspect='auto', extent=[grating_time.to_numpy()[0], grating_time.to_numpy()[-1], 0, image_height])
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Grating')
plt.show()
```

This is what I get with the current code which is far from what I want
[image]
Any ideas on how to fix this or even better make it so I have blocks of black and white stripes (lets say 3 white and 2 black) plotted in the regions defined by my provided start and end indices?

Comment: What is the error or what is your expected output?

Comment: A few days ago I posted an answer (I'd say an excellent answer), but I've received zero feedback from you.  Do you have solved on your own? do you just don't care anymore? or have you found my solution satisfactory?

Comment: Dear gboffi thank you very much for taking the time to look into this and find such an elegant solution! I tried it and indeed it saved me a lot of time and effort. It took me some time to receive it since I was away and only now got through my emails and notifications. Thanks again! It solved my problem nicely, I hope it is useful to others as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your approach (`imshow`) may work, but it is somehow cumbersome to get everything proper.

The plot above was obtained using [`ax.axvspan`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvspan.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-axvspan), once for each of the white boxes (aka stimuli intervals) and a variable number of times for the black stripes in each white box.

An even simpler approach would be drawing vertical black lines, but using `ax.axvspan` repeatedly gives better results, or at least so it seems to me.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import show, subplots
from numpy import linspace

# no. of stimuli, no. of black stripes
NS, NB = 10, 4

# for simplicity, the stimuli intervals are equispaced 
intervals = linspace(0, 300, NS+NS+2)[1:-1].reshape(-1,2)

fig, ax = subplots(figsize=(12,3), layout='constrained')
ax.set_facecolor('lightgray')
ax.set_ylim((0, 50))
ax.set_xlim((0, 300))

for interval in intervals:
    inner_xs = linspace(*interval, NB+NB+2)
    ax.axvspan(*interval, ec='k', fc='w', lw=0.3)
    for sub in zip(inner_xs[1::2], inner_xs[2::2]): 
        ax.axvspan(*sub, ec='k', fc='k', lw=0.3)

show()
```